# How to open a link/url automatically from PowerPoint?

Tags: ms-office, powerpoint

I have a link/url in PPT and I want to open it when the slide appears and without any click on it. Is it possible?
Thank you

Comment: What's about the solution I posted - is this running in your environment without error? BTW - your EDIT is more like to see as a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft PowerPoint fires the `OnSlideShowPageChange()` event for every slide that is shown during the slide show. You can use this facility to call any macro when certain slides are displayed. PowerPoint passes a reference to the SlideShowWindow as parameter to the `OnSlideShowPageChange()` event.

I assume you have a hyperlink on slide 2. So, copy following code in a VBA modul:

```vb
' --- The following macro displays a message when the second slide is shown.
' --- You are asked to open or not to open the link.
' --- The first link on slide 2 is opened when you click the OK button.

Sub OnSlideShowPageChange(ByVal SSW As SlideShowWindow)
    If SSW.View.CurrentShowPosition = 2 Then
        MsgBox "Second slide in the slide show"
        result = MsgBox("Open URL?", vbOKCancel)
        If result = vbOK Then
            ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Hyperlinks(1).Follow
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Of course you can delete useless lines of code for your needs to step over the message and question.

Comment: The code worked correctly! Now I have a different Issue haha. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is no "easy" way to do this. When you try to achieve something that is non standard in Office, you have to use VBA.

This code line should do the trick in your case :

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Hyperlinks(1).Follow
```

If you're not familiar with using VBA in Ppt, I would suggest having a look at guides, there are a bunch of them online :)

I hope this helps !
Have a nice day